# How can i use onUpgrade Method?

Tags: java, android

In my Android project, I put the table I created using DB Browser for SQlite into the assets folder. I can connect to the database and retrieve the necessary information. I would like to ask you to update the database on the computer and put it in the assets folder and update it with the onUpgrade metadata. How can I do that?

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
Log.d(LOG_TAG, " --- onUpgrade database from " + oldVersion
+ " to " + newVersion + " version --- ");
if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2)
{
this.getReadableDatabase();
try {
copyDataBase();
} catch (IOException e) {

throw new Error("Veritabany kopyalanamady");

}
}
```

The code didn't work for me.

Comment: Creating a assert folder procedure is their just follow this below url https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-ship-sqlite-database-with-apk-copy-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder-to-data-example

Answer (score 0):

```
if (oldVersion<newVersion){
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
    copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Veritabany kopyalanamady");
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.